# How to move multiple users to multiple OUs importing users from CSV and filtering by department

Tags: powershell

New to powershell and scripting in general. Trying to improve automation in our onboarding process, we have to move multiple user accounts to multiple OUs every couple of months.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$dept1 = "OU=Path1,DC=SOMEWHERE,DC=OUTTHERE"
$dept2 = "OU=Path2,DC=SOMEWHERE,DC=OUTTHERE"
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Incoming.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Filter {Department -eq "Dept1"} | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $dept1
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Filter {Department -eq "Dept2"} | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $dept2
}
```

This actually moves ALL users with the department marked into the path I have set.. but I only want it to look at those users in the csv and then filter their departments from AD - not the CSV. I feel like I'm missing a step but I've searched everywhere and tried the get-help. I feel like I need to get the identity, then search/filter against something else but I'm not quite sure how. Would appreciate any help.

**edit**

Okay, if I run the following:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Department -eq "Dept1"} -Properties Department
```

It returns everyone that fits that property but how do I compare those to the $samAccountName and ONLY try to move those accounts or run the commands against the accounts on the list? When I ran the second half of the command it tried to move them all and failed.

```
Move-ADObject $samAccountName -Target $dept1
```

I feel dumb.

Comment: according to this page >>> Get-ADUser (activedirectory) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps <<< you cannot use both `-Identity` and `-Filter`. so i suspect what is happening is the 1st is being ignored ... leaving you with just the filter. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you Lee. I was unaware of how to properly read the parameter sets. I know now.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to feel dumb. You're not and everyone feels that way at times when trying to learn a new thing. You're also here asking for help, so you're ahead of the game compared to a lot of others.

@Lee_Daily's comment is correct that `Get-ADUser` doesn't support using both `-Identity` and `-Filter` in the same command. They're part of different [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-parameter-sets). You can tell from the syntax output of `Get-Help Get-ADUser` or the [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser). Both show 3 different sets of parameters and Identity and Filter are not in the same one. What's odd is that your original script should have thrown an error because you tried to use both in the same command. No need to worry about that now though.

Here's a typical way one might approach this task. First, you query the user's details including the department you want to make a decision on. Then, you write your condition and perform the appropriate action. Doing it this way means you're only querying AD once for each user in your CSV rather than twice like your original script which is good for script performance and load on your AD. The inside of your `ForEach-Object` loop might look something like this. *Note the addition of `-Properties department` in Get-ADUser. We need to ask for it explicitly because department isn't returned in the default result set.*

```bsh
# all of this goes inside your existing ForEach-Object loop

$u = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Properties department

if ($u.Department -eq 'Dept1') {
    $u | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $dept1
} elseif ($u.Department -eq 'Dept2') {
    $u | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $dept2
}
```

Now let's talk about some alternative ways you might approach this.

The first way sort of flips things around so you end up only calling `Get-ADUser` once total, but end up doing a lot more filtering/processing on the client side. It's not my favorite, but it sets things up to understand my preferred solution. In particular, the `Get-ADUser` call uses the `-LDAPFilter` parameter. [LDAP filter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax) is a little strange if you've never seen it before and this particular example could use the more common `-Filter` syntax just as easily. But in the next example it would be much more difficult and learning LDAP filter syntax enables you to query AD from anything rather than just PowerShell.

```bsh
# instead of immediately looping on the CSV we imported, save it to a variable
$incoming = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Incoming.csv"

# then we make a single AD query for all users in either Dept1 or Dept2
$users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(department=Dept1)(department=Dept2))' -Properties department

# now we filter the set of users from AD by department and whether they're in the CSV and do the moves as appropriate
$users | Where-Object { $_.department -eq 'Dept1' -and
    $_.samAccountName -in $incoming.samAccountName } | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $dept1
$users | Where-Object { $_.department -eq 'Dept2' -and
    $_.samAccountName -in $incoming.samAccountName } | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $dept2
```

The benefit of this method is the single AD round trip for users rather than one for each in the CSV. But there are a lot more local loops checking the samAccountNames in the results with the samAccountNames from the CSV which can get expensive cpu-wise if your CSV and/or AD is huge.

The final example tweaks the previous example by expanding our LDAP filter and making AD do more of the work. AD is *ridiculously* good at returning LDAP query results. It's been fine-tuned over decades to do exactly that. So we should take advantange of it whenever possible.

Essentially what we're going to do is create a giant 'OR' filter out of the samAccountNames from the CSV so that when we get our results, the only check we have to do is the check for department. The way I verbalize this query in my head is that we're asking AD to "Return all users where SamAccountName is A or B or C or D, etc and Department is Dept1 or Dept2. The general form of the filter will look like this *(spaces included for readability)*.

```
(& <SAM FILTER> <DEPT FILTER> )

# Where <DEPT FILTER> is copied from the previous example and
# <SAM FILTER> is similar but for each entry in the CSV like this
(|(samAccountName=a)(samAccountName=b)(samAccountName=c)...)
```

So let's see it in action.

```bsh
# save our CSV to a variable like before
$incoming = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\Incoming.csv"

# build the SAM FILTER
$samInner = $incoming.samAccountName -join ')(samAccountName='
$samFilter = "(|(samAccountName=$samInner))"

# build the DEPT FILTER
$deptFilter = '(|(department=Dept1)(department=Dept2))'

# combine the two with an LDAP "AND"
$ldapFilter = "(&$($samFilter)$($deptFilter))"

# now make our single AD query using the final filter
$users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter -Properties department

# and finally filter and move the users based on department
$users | Where-Object { $_.department -eq 'Dept1' } | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $dept1
$users | Where-Object { $_.department -eq 'Dept2' } | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $dept2
```

There are more efficient ways to build the LDAP filter string, but I wanted to keep things simple for readability. It's also a lot easier to read with better PowerShell syntax highlighting than StackOverflow's. But hopefully you get the gist.

The only limitation with using this method is when your incoming CSV file is huge. There's a maximum size that your LDAP filter can be. Though I'm not sure what it is and I've never personally reached it with roughly ~4000 users in the filter. But even if you have to split up your incoming CSV file into batches of a few thousand users, it's still likely to be more efficient than the other examples.

Comment: Ryan, thanks so much for the clarification and instruction. Being fairly new, I was unaware that the Get-Help parameter sets worked that way. Thank you.

I do have a further question though - it looks like above you are querying all of AD for their department and storing them in $u. How do you compare that to a list or csv and ONLY move those users to the target path? A bit of further explanation, we typically have to move 10-20 users from a disabled users OU to their appropriate department OU every week.

Comment: Or are you saying that will query my csv file already because it will be placed inside of the ForEach-Object loop? I think I misread it first.

Comment: The latter is correct. This code is inside your existing ForEach-Object. So it's running once per user in the file you imported with Import-CSV.

Comment: Great, thanks Ryan. Will test this tomorrow at the office and report/select the answer if everything works out!

Comment: Ryan, the top two work great. I can't begin to wrap my head against the LDAP syntax yet but will look to learn it a little bit more. I just wanted to thank you so much for your in depth responses and teaching. I really do appreciate it. Can I ask, where can I read about 

`$u.Department -eq 'Dept2'`

More specifically, where do I read about how the "." parameter comes into play against that previously defined variable. It's a hard thing to google if I'm not exactly sure what it's called. Thanks again!!

Comment: The `.blah` is just the standard way to access an object's properties in PowerShell. The `$u` in the first example is the object returned by Get-ADUser. A nice way to see what properties a particular object has is to pipe it to `Get-Member` (or `gm` for short). So do something like `$u | gm`.

Comment: Heh, wow. That one simple gm command is awesome. Thanks again for the explanation.